# JRuby - TypeError: no public constructors for #<Class:>

Tags: jruby

I'm trying to use the java.security.KeyPairGenerator via JRuby 1.7 RC2 as per the following code:

```
require 'java'
kp = java.security.KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")
puts kp #java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate@45f177b
```

However, when I try to call initialize i.e.

```
kp.initialize(2048)
```

I get the following exception:-

```
TypeError: no public constructors for #<Class:0x7efe8e7a>
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little clash between ruby's `initialize` method (which is a constructor in the ruby world) and the method in this particular java class.

Normally, one does not call `initialize` on a ruby class (you call `new` instead), but anyway it seems to be causing some confusion for the interpreter.

If you look at the output of `kp.methods` you'll see JRuby has added a `initialize__method` to circumvent the clash (note double underscore).

Try this:

```
require 'java'
kp = java.security.KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")
kp.initialize__method(2048)
```

Another technique is to use [java_method](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby), which is also useful when the interpreter is having trouble picking the right overload.

E.g.:

```
m = kp.java_method :initialize, [Java::int]
m.call(2048)
```

Comment: Thanks very much a nice description/answer for the problem!